# How to search text from pdf in swift 5?

Tags: search, swift5, pdfkit

I am currently working on a pdf Document App. It am trying to apply search on using textField. I search lot about this stuff on internet but not able to find healthy solution. If someone have know plz help me????

Comment: Please provide more clarity as to what you’re trying to do and what you’ve already tried.

Comment: I had a pdf file which contain 19 pages. If user search for any word (by typing in textfield and press search button) if result found then pdf should move to current page and highlight the text.

Comment: It’s a bit more involved than you‘d expect I’m afraid, but you could start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/1436078-beginfindstring

Comment: @P.A.Monsaille thanks but i make it almost a week ago.I build my own algo